# Vim で「:call dein#install()」実行時にエラーとなる

Tags: macos, vim

MacOS iTerm2にてVimで `:call dein#install()` 実行時に下記エラーとなります。
しかし、最初から入っているターミナルでは正常に終了します。プラグインもちゃんとインストールされます。
ターミナルによってvimrcで最適な設定が必要だったりするのでしょうか。

上記、どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
[dein] Target plugins are not found.
[dein] You may have used the wrong plugin name, or all of the plugins are already installed.
```

Answer (score 1):

これはdein.vimが新しくインストールすべきプラグインが見つけられなかった(=すでにプラグインは正常にインストールされてる)というメッセージとのことです。このまま使用しても良いと思われます。
dein.vimのドキュメントのリンクを添付しましたので関数の役割を確認ください。

また、お使いのvimrcを質問と一緒に添付してくださるとよりお伝えしやすいです。

[参照]
https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim/blob/master/doc/dein.txt#L156-L275

Comment: ありがとうございます。そういうことでしたか、助かりました。